# Linking subprocesses in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

Hi I had a question about linking input and output with sub-processes in python. I am trying to simplify the program by skipping the output of one step by passing it to another subprocess rather than output it to a file. Then open another process to run on that file.

E.g. First process uses SAMTOOLS to output a specific chromosome from a large bam file.
So...
bigfile.bam is read in and outputs chromosome22.bam

The next subprocess uses BEDTOOLS to convert that chromosome22.bam to chromosome22.bed
So...
chromosome22.bam is read in and outputs chromosome22.bed

What I want to do is pass the stdout of the first process into the second so there is no need for the intermediate file.

So far I have this...

```
for x in 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,'X','Y':
   subprocess.call("%s view -bh %s %s > %s/%s/%s.bam" % (samtools,bam,x,bampath,out,x), shell=True)
```

This makes the chromosome[1-22,X,Y].bam files. But can I avoid this and put another subprocess command in the same loop to convert them to bed files?

The command for bed conversion is:

```
bedpath/bedtools bamtobed -i [bamfile] > [bedfile]
```

Comment: How about using a pipe? `|` is the magic symbol. Since you are invoking a shell command, there isn't really much python involved here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use python here. Much easier in *shell*. But essentially, it works the same as in python.

If bedtools can read from stdin, you can e.g. do

```
#!/bin/sh
for x in `seq 1 22` X Y; do
   $samtools view -bh $bam $x | $bedtools bamtobed > $bampath/$out/$x.bam
done
```

Depending on how `bedtools` was desinged, you might also need to use `-i -` to have it read from `stdin`.

If you stick with python, I strongly recommend about learning how to do this

1. without doing it in all shell,
2. without producing shell commands, that you need to escape properly to avoid errors

`subprocess` is more *safe to use* when you use the array-based syntax and *no shell*.
Make that *two* subprocess invocations, one for each command. See http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline for more details.

```
cmd1 = [samtools, "view", "-bh", bam, x]
cmd2 = [bedtools, "bamtobed"]

c1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
c2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, stdin=c1.stdout, stdout=open(outputfilename, "w"))
c1.stdout.close()
c2.communicate()
```

Comment: c2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, stdin=c1.stdout, stdout=open("/home/dmacmillan/22.bed", "w"))

At this point I get an error:
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: I couldn't get these solutions to work, but I did manage to figure it out by doing the piping in one subprocess.

    subprocess.call("%s view -bh %s 22 | %s/bedtools bamtobed -i > /home/dmacmillan/22.bed " % (samtools,bam,bedtools), shell=True)

Comment: That actually creates *three* subprocesses at least. One for the shell, another one for samtools, and one for bedtools. Have a look at `Popen` and the various `subprocess` examples (which are really good).

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look at the [replacing shell pipeline](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) example in the documentation.

```
output=$(dmesg | grep hda)
```

becomes:

```
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

The explanation is:

> The `p1.stdout.close()` call after starting the p2 is important in order for p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits before p1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the pipe functionality. See if you can read from stdin for the bamtobed process ... if you can, try the following. This way you save on the disk IO time assuming the processing load is light.

### SLIGHT modification:

proc1.stdout is now the stdin for the 2nd process.

```
proc1 = subprocess.call("%s view -bh %s %s" % (samtools,bam,x,bampath,out,x), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

proc2 = subprocess.call("bedpath/bedtools bamtobed > %s" % (outFileName, ), shell=True, stdin=proc1.stdout)
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if the last assignment works. Shouldn't the FD be passed in the `call` statement already?